# Convert java rest request to php code

Tags: java, php, rest, curl

How can I convert this java code to php.

```
server = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection  = (HttpURLConnection) server.openConnection() ;
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod( method );
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",mimeType );
    if( requestParameter != null)
    {
        CyberoamLogger.appLog.debug(MODULE+":"+METHOD+"Request parameter: "+requestParameter.toString());
        out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( urlConnection.getOutputStream() ) );
        out.write(requestParameter.toString());
        out.flush();
        out.close() ;
    }

    urlConnection.connect();    
    strbuf = new StringBuffer();            
     is= urlConnection.getInputStream()   ;   
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];        
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = is.read(buffer)))
        strbuf.append(new String(buffer, 0, n));
    is.close();
    strResponse=strbuf.toString();
    CyberoamLogger.appLog.debug(MODULE+METHOD+ " WS Responce in String  : "+strResponse);
    urlConnection.disconnect();
```

When I try following php code I get The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (). error

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    echo curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the content type header with your curl:

```
$mimeType = "application/json";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type: $mimeType"));
// equivalent to your java urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",mimeType );
```

And here is an example of preparing json:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'alex',
    'value' => '100'
);
$json_data = json_encode($data); // {"name":"alex","value":"100"}
```

Comment: mimeType is a java variable which contain "application/json". In php when I put CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER array("Content-Type: application/json");

Comment: It gives me error The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

Comment: @SiddharthNagar your json data may be not correct in format. check how you can use correct formatted json from my updated answer.